# Are there low cost options for producing high pressure at low flow rates?

Tags: sensors

I'm looking for a low-cost way for a device to produce up to 4 bar pressure.  Flow rate at that pressure almost doesn't matter; 2L per minute would be ample.  All the options available seem very over-specced for this job - or maybe I'm just googling the wrong thing?

For anyone curious, I'm trying to measure the depth of a water column.  Depth is up to 40m.  I want to measure by putting a piece of PVC tube down the column, pumping air down it until it comes out the other end, then measuring the pressure at the surface.  The whole volume of the (4mm internal diameter) tube is about half a litre so a flow of 2LPM would mean pumping for 15s with each measurement.

Apologies for the slightly inaccurate tag; I couldn't find anything really on-topic and don't have the reputation to create new tags.

Comment: electric bicycle pump ... or even a manual bicycle pump

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Comment: Hi @Ben. This is an actual problem that I have; I need a type of pump that is high(ish) pressure, low flow and low cost. I don't know much about pumps and what types are suitable for what. I'm what way is that not a practical, answerable question?

Comment: @Tom - It's a shopping question. You've got a set of specifications you can google. We could recommend what we think is appropriate, but there's probably not going to be anything that exactly meets your needs. Any links or products we suggest might be superseded by more appropriate products later, or maybe products get discontinued. There's no **knowledge** to impart here, just lists of potentially relevant products.

Comment: But for the premise of your question - if you have a PVC tube you can put in some water, why not just mark the outside of the pipe with the length of the pipe? When the bottom of the pipe is the bottom of the water then whatever marking is level with the surface of the water is how deep the water is. You don't even need an air pump or pressure gauge or anything.

Comment: @Chuck I disagree.  I'm not looking for an Amazon link, but rather "X-type pumps are cheap and can easily achieve 4 bar at that sort of flow rate."  That's general knowledge that is unlikely to change quickly.

Comment: And to answer your second question, the water surface is X metres down a borehole, where X is a number between 2 and 35 depending on how much rain has fallen recently and how much water has been extracted, and I'd like to be able to measure it without having to disassemble the well head every time.  If you think there's a stack exchange site more suited to this question then by all means say so - this was the closest I could spot.

Comment: Have you looked at electric tire inflators? I don't know what your budget is but they're about 50-ish dollars and can do 4 bar no problem. You could also just keep compressed air bottles like for paintball markers. Pre-compress the air and you don't need to wait around for the little compressor to charge the pipe.

Comment: This question might be more suitable for: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/